# How to stop UILabel from trimming the space at the end?

Tags: ios, uilabel, arabic, spaces, trim

I have a UILabel acting like a ticker so every 0.09 seconds the text is being changed, but when a space comes at the end of the label it is being trimmed, so it is looking like the ticker is lagging.

Here’s the code:

```
[self setTickerLabel: [ [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40)]];


[self.tickerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:TICKER_FONT_SIZE]];

self.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.result];


self.tickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

[self.tickerLabel setText:self.text];

[self.tickerLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TICKER_RATE target:self selector: @selector(nudgeTicker:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[self.view addSubview:self.tickerLabel];
```

The nudge Ticker method does the following:

```
NSString* firstLetter = [self.text substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
NSString* remainder = [self.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,[self.text length]-1)];
self.text=[remainder stringByAppendingString: firstLetter];
self.tickerLabel.text=self.text;
```

I really need some help. How can I fix this? By the way the text of the UILabel is in Arabic.

Comment: 0.09 milliseconds, really? I assume you mean 90 milliseconds.

Comment: What do you mean by trimmed? Does the label have some background color so that it's clear the space is getting dropped? Is the size getting trimmed or something else?

Comment: @rdelmar yea i meant 0.09 seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but one solution would be to use an attributed string in your label and include a transparent period (".") at the end of the string.

Just replace your `nudgeTicker:` method.

```
- (void)nudgeTicker:(id)target {
    NSString* firstLetter = [self.text substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
    NSString* remainder = [self.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,[self.text length]-1)];
    self.text=[remainder stringByAppendingString: firstLetter];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", self.text]];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length-1)];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(string.length-1,1)];
    self.tickerLabel.attributedText = string;
}
```

Comment: You are a genius.

Comment: you are a genius.